# how to add conditions in OrientDB ETL

Tags: orientdb

I have a CSV file contains addresses for restaurants and other places, and at one colomun I have 'N' for neighborhood and 'S' (and not both) for street. If a line have the letter 'N' I want to link it to a vertex named neighborhood, and if it had 'S' I  want to link it to a vertex named Street

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide details about your efforts for better responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **LET** block to assign the vertex class name as result of the expression. Example

```
{ let: { name: "vClass", value : "street" }, if: "$input.type = 'S'" },
{ let: { name: "vClass", value : "neighborhood" }, if: "$input.type = 'N'" },
{ vertex: { class: "$vClass" }
```

Comment: thanks Luca, and thank you for OrientDB it's a great product.